# Strange MySQL ordering behaviour when selecting text field

Tags: mysql

I managed to stumble on strange mysql behaviour I haven't noticed before.

MySQL Server version: 5.5.38

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testing` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`a` int(11) NOT NULL,
`b` int(11) NOT NULL,
`c` text,
`d` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `testing` (`id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) VALUES
(1, 1, 11, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:26:00'),
(2, 2, 22, NULL, '2015-01-08 18:35:00'),
(3, 4, 44, NULL, '2015-01-08 12:17:00'),
(4, 5, 44, NULL, '2015-01-08 12:53:00'),
(5, 5, 44, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:26:00'),
(6, 5, 44, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:26:00'),
(7, 5, 44, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:26:00'),
(8, 5, 44, NULL, '2015-01-08 09:37:00'),
(9, 5, 22, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:26:00'),
(10, 5, 33, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:26:00'),
(11, 5, 44, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:40:00'),
(12, 5, 32, NULL, '2015-01-08 08:26:00');
```

Query

```
SELECT id, IF( a =5
AND b =44, 0, 1 ) AS active, d
FROM `testing`
ORDER BY active, d DESC
```

returns

```
id  active  d
4   0       2015-01-08 12:53:00
8   0       2015-01-08 09:37:00
11  0       2015-01-08 08:40:00
7   0       2015-01-08 08:26:00
5   0       2015-01-08 08:26:00
6   0       2015-01-08 08:26:00
2   1       2015-01-08 18:35:00
3   1       2015-01-08 12:17:00
10  1       2015-01-08 08:26:00
9   1       2015-01-08 08:26:00
1   1       2015-01-08 08:26:00
12  1       2015-01-08 08:26:00
```

but query

```
SELECT id, IF( a =5
AND b =44, 0, 1 ) AS active, d, c
FROM `testing`
ORDER BY active, d DESC
```

returns

```
id  active  d                       c
4   0       2015-01-08 12:53:00     NULL
8   0       2015-01-08 09:37:00     NULL
11  0       2015-01-08 08:40:00     NULL
5   0       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
6   0       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
7   0       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
2   1       2015-01-08 18:35:00     NULL
3   1       2015-01-08 12:17:00     NULL
1   1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
9   1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
10  1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
12  1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
```

How can a sql query result order change by selecting additional field? Is there any reason for that to happen or is this a mysql bug? I noticed that if I change the type of field c for a VARCHAR(255) instead of TEXT, then the order remains the same for the both query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug.  The issue is that sorting in MySQL (and SQL in general) is not stable.  That is, rows with the same key values for the `order by` can appear in any order.

You have rows with exactly the same values for the `order by keys`, such as:

```
1   1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
9   1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
10  1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
12  1       2015-01-08 08:26:00     NULL
```

(The second and third columns are the `order by` keys.)

When you sort the data, these could appear in any order -- with or without additional columns.  For a stable sort, you should always include an identity column:

```
ORDER BY active, d DESC, id
```

Comment: The sorting is not stable for performance reasons. Since all those rows are equivalent with respect to the specified sorting criteria, MySQL has no reason to put more effort in it. If one needs those rows sorted in a specified order, they need to add more sorting criteria to pinpoint the desired order.

Comment: @axiac . . . Sorting is not stable because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There simply is no ordering defined when the keys are the same.

Comment: There always is an order in the physical representation. Either the `PK` or the order of records on the storage medium could be used. But, as I said, there is no point in working hard to produce an order when the query does not ask for it.

Comment: So the reason behind the fact, that it works well with VARCHAR field type instead of TEXT, is because TEXT field is stored off the table with the table just having a pointer to the location of the actual storage and this mixes up the original order of rows?

Answer (score 0):

> There is no bug, you are adding c column which contains null value,
>   and even null cannot be compared to null (or NULL is unique in
>   itself). Therefore you are getting different result.

Comment: So why the order does not change when I use field type VARCHAR instead of TEXT for c?

Comment: Check when you convert your column to text, what is the default value for column c.

Comment: Default value is NULL for col c and all cols have NULL as a value.

Comment: Actually it does not matter if col c is nullable or not. The behaviour remains if c is valued with empty string instead of NULL.